# Writing JSON with key as a object of a class

Tags: json

I have a class like,

```
public class foo
{
    String a;
    Integer b;
}
```

Now, I want to use the object of this class as a key in the key value pair of JSON. And, I want an array of such JSON's.

For example, it will be something like,

```
"{"a": "hello1","b": 23}": "40",
"{"a": "hello2","b": 34}": "41",
"{"a": "hello3","b": 36}": "42"
```

I just wanted to know if something like this is possible? And if yes, how do I represent it in JSON because clearly the above isn't a valid JSON. I have tried multiple combinations (by removing the double quotes at multiple places but none of them worked).

Thanks!

Comment: `{"{\"a\": \"hello1\",\"b\": \"23\"}": "40", "{\"a\": \"hello2\",\"b\": \"34\"}": "41", "{\"a\": \"hello3\",\"b\": \"36\"}": "42"}` ? Since you can write JSON within JSON?

Comment: @Larme, isn't there any way I can remove the escape characters/slashes for the first json?